# document.activeElement.id is not working

Tags: javascript

I am developing an application  for device. and i want to know the current focused anchor.

for this i used **document.activeElement.id**. It is working fine on webkit but not working on older browser. 
So i used

```
           $(":a").focus(function () {
            id = this.id;
                });
```

It is also not working. I go through meny website and i found that .focus method wil work for only **input** tag.

So please give me IDea  for this problem . If it will be  purely javascript it will be better .

Any help will be appricated

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$(document).on('focus','a', function(e) {
    id = this.id;
});
```

The `focus` event does not bubble natively in all browsers, but jQuery should normalize this, making it possible to delegate it to the document.